# Schema for Image Gallery Photo?

Tags: images, schema.org

I have an image gallery and will be using the [ImageGallery](https://schema.org/ImageGallery) Schema to markup the various images.

Each photo within the gallery will also have it's own page that will contain a longer description along with the ability for people to comment on the photo.

For this page, which contains only one image, should I use the ImageGallery schema or should I use another schema to markup this individual page?

What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the type `ImageGallery` for a single image’s detail page doesn’t seem to be appropriate, because, well, this page is not a gallery.

The type [`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage) could be used instead:

> A page devoted to a single item, such as a particular product or hotel.